# How to execute VSTO AddIn code as VBA Macro

Tags: vba, ms-office, vsto

Normally I can assign a VBA macro to a shape. However, I would like to write some set of instructions in C# and have it as a external method in the AddIn library that can be executed after clicking on that shape (or any other object that is on the spreadsheet and **not** in the ribbon, which accepts only macros to be assigned to it).

Answer (score 0):

You are free to call add-in's code from VBA. See [Walkthrough: Calling Code in a VSTO Add-in from VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608614.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

Note, you are free to handle the object model events in the add-in as well.